# An apparently "simple" limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Let $c$ and $h$ be real values.
I was using *Mathematica* to compute the limit $(h \rightarrow \infty)$ of the following expression:

$$
\frac{\left(h^2 +c^2 h^2 + \sqrt{4 h^2+\left(h^2+c^2 h^2\right)^2}\right)^2}{4\left(h^2 + \frac{1}{4}\left(h^2 +c^2 h^2 + \sqrt{4 h^2+\left(h^2+c^2 h^2\right)^2}\right)^2\right)}\text{//FullSimplify}
$$
which is equal to
$$=\frac{2}{4+(1+c^2)^2 h^2 - (1+c^2)\sqrt{4h^2+(1+c^2)^2 h^4}}$$

Just as the rough estimate anyone can make by counting powers of $h$ in the numerator and denominator predicts, the *Mathematica* function `Limit[f[h], h -> ∞]` gives $1$ in the nonsimplified case and gives $0$ in the simplified case.

Now, I am a little confused about whether the correct limit is $1$ or $0$ ? And is the function `Limit` supposed to work that way as to not being able to distinguish the correct result from the wrong one ?

Here is the *Mathematica* code

```
a = (h^2 + c^2 h^2 + Sqrt[4 h^2 + (h^2 + c^2 h^2)^2])^2/(
   4 (h^2 + 
      1/4 (h^2 + c^2 h^2 + Sqrt[4 h^2 + (h^2 + c^2 h^2)^2])^2)) // 
   FullSimplify;

Limit[a, h -> Infinity]
```

as you know, you can add or remove the `//FullSimplify` at the end of the definition for $a$ to switch between the two cases.

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in the comments below, I have reported this as a bug to Wolfram support. They wrote back, were very polite and thankful, mentioned that this issue has been forwarded to their developer team and recommended to use `Assumptions` in order to be sure that everything goes well and additionally even speed up the computation.

**EDIT:**

Fun fact - 5 years later, if I try to evaluate the above limit in Mathematica

```
$Version
```

> `"11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"`

I get exactly the same discrepancy in the two limits as described above. Which means, Wolfram has ignored this bug in the `Limit` routine in the meantime.

Comment: @Artes: OK, I will report this as a bug.

Comment: Just to make sure - I am right in believing that `0` is the right answer, aren't I?

Comment: In Mma 8.0.1 (Mac) both expressions give a limit of 1. Also looking at the series expansion `Series[a, {h, \[Infinity], 6}]` it looks like `1` is the more reasonable answer.

Comment: I confirm this problem in version 7 on Windows.  What version are you using?

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke : I use Mathematica 9 on linux. Try `Series[a//FullSimplify, {h, \[Infinity], 6}]` to see the leading `1` vanish. Also I just `Plot3D`-ted their ratio (simplified and non-simplified) in some region and it is 1 up to machine error.

Comment: @Kagaratsch interesting, i'll look into that. Another thing i found: try `Limit[a, h -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> c > 0]`. This gives 1 as a limit in both cases. Without the assumption it is 0.

Comment: Yes, the `Assumptions -> c > 0` now also gives `1` for me. So the bug must actually be in `FullSimplify` and not `Series` and `Limit`.

Comment: @Kagaratsch: 1 is the correct result....

Comment: @Fabian: Thank you, now I too am certain that 1 is correct.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Since the WRI people say they are aware of it, they'll say it is not a bug. Nevertheless one might expect a warning that some inconsitencies would appear. Since there is no warning one can encounter serious troubles. However `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` work well if one uses assumptions therein or in `Limit`.

Comment: @Artes I agree - at least the documentation should have a warning and an example how to deal with this sort of case.  I wish one could set the domain to `Reals` the way one can with `Reduce`.

Comment: Actually `Limit` has been considerably improved in the time frame under question. This particular bug has not been fixed, but inductive reasoning from a sample size of 1 is probably not a statistically sound notion.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You are right, I've edited to formulate it a bit better.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a bit more to the story.  Mathematica treats variables as complex by default, and I for one have had trouble figuring out how `Limit` figures out how to treat variables such as `c` in this case.

**Some analysis**

First, let's examine `a0` (`= a` in OP) with the assumption that`c` is real:

```
a0 = (h^2 + c^2 h^2 + Sqrt[4 h^2 + (h^2 + c^2 h^2)^2])^2 /
       (4 (h^2 + 1/4 (h^2 + c^2 h^2 + Sqrt[4 h^2 + (h^2 + c^2 h^2)^2])^2));

aR = FullSimplify[a0, h > 0 && c \[Element] Reals]
(* -> (h + c^2 h + Sqrt[4 + (1 + c^2)^2 h^2])/(2 Sqrt[ 4 + (1 + c^2)^2 h^2]) *)
```

> $$\frac{\sqrt{\left(c^2+1\right)^2 h^2+4}+c^2 h+h}{2 \sqrt{\left(c^2+1\right)^2 h^2+4}}$$

It simplifies a little if we split the fraction up:

```
1/2 + Factor[aR - 1/2]
(* -> 1/2 + ((1 + c^2) h)/(2 Sqrt[4 + (1 + c^2)^2 h^2]) *)
```

> $$\frac{\left(c^2+1\right) h}{2 \sqrt{\left(c^2+1\right)^2 h^2+4}}+\frac{1}{2}$$

And let's look at it if `c` is an imaginary number `k I`:

```
aI = FullSimplify[a0 /. c -> k I, h > 0 && k \[Element] Reals]
(* -> (h - h k^2 + Sqrt[4 + h^2 (-1 + k^2)^2])/(2 Sqrt[4 + h^2 (-1 + k^2)^2]) *)
```

> $$\frac{\sqrt{h^2 \left(k^2-1\right)^2+4}-h k^2+h}{2 \sqrt{h^2 \left(k^2-1\right)^2+4}}$$

Again it simplifies if we split the fraction up:

```
1/2 + Factor[aI - 1/2]
(* -> 1/2 - (h (-1 + k) (1 + k))/(2 Sqrt[4 + h^2 (-1 + k^2)^2]) *)
```

> $$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{h (k-1) (k+1)}{2 \sqrt{h^2 \left(k^2-1\right)^2+4}}$$

We see if `c` is `+/-I` (if `k` is `+/-1`), the fraction is `0`, so the limit is `1/2`.  If `k > 1` or `k < -1`, then the limit of the fraction is `-1/2`, so the limit of `a0` is `0`.  And if `-1 < k < 1`, then the limit of the fraction is `+1/2`, so the limit of `a0` is `1`.  If `c` is real, then up above one can see the limit of the fraction is `1/2`, so the limit of `a0` is `1`.

Here are some examples:

```
Table[Print["c = ", c, " --> ", HoldForm[Limit[a0, h -> Infinity]], 
   " = ", Limit[a0, h -> Infinity]], {c, {1, I/2, I, 2 I}}];
```

> ```
> c = 1 --> Limit[a0, h -> Infinity] = 1   
> c = I/2 --> Limit[a0, h -> Infinity] = 1
> c = I --> Limit[a0, h -> Infinity] = 1/2
> c = 2 I --> Limit[a0, h -> Infinity] = 0
> ```

### How to find the limit sought

One should probably use assumptions:

```
a1 = Simplify[a];
a2 = FullSimplify[a];

Block[{$Assumptions = c \[Element] Reals}, Limit[a0, h -> Infinity]]
Block[{$Assumptions = c \[Element] Reals}, Limit[a1, h -> Infinity]]
Block[{$Assumptions = c \[Element] Reals}, Limit[a2, h -> Infinity]]
(* -> 1, 1, 1 *)
```

Then the answers are correct.

### EDIT - Addendum

Prompted to investigate further by various comments, I have something to add, including what the actual limit for a generic complex $c$ is (which one might expect Mathematica could return as the correct answer).  This goes beyond the current version of the OP's question, which stipulates that $c$ be real, but I hope it sheds some light on the issues `Limit` has dealing with this function.

**What should the limit be?**

Working it out by hand, I get the limit for a complex $c$ to be

$$\begin{cases}
 1        & {\rm Im}(c)^2-{\rm Re}(c)^2<1 \\
 {1}/{2}  & {\rm Im}(c)^2-{\rm Re}(c)^2=1 \\
 0        & {\rm Im}(c)^2-{\rm Re}(c)^2>1
\end{cases}$$

Here is a plot of the real part of `a0` vs. `c` when `h = 100`.  The imaginary parts are nearly zero, and the real part is nearly equal to the limit.  You can see the discontinuity forming along the red cliff.  The limits at six test values are shown by the green spheres.  We will use these **test values** for `c` again later.

```
testvalues = {1, I/2, I, 2 I, 1 + 2 I, 2 + 2 I};

Show[ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[{Re[c], Im[c], Re[a0]} /. {c -> r E^(I q), h -> 100.}],
  {r, 0, 3}, {q, 0, 2 π}, PlotPoints -> {50, 150}, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
  Exclusions -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#2^2 - #1^2 &, #4 &, #5 &}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Red, GrayLevel[0.5], GrayLevel[0.5]}, 
  Mesh -> {{-1, 0, 1, 2}; {0.97, 1.03}, 11, {0, π/2, π, (3 π)/2}},
   MeshShading -> {{{Yellow, Red, Lighter[Purple, 0.5]}}}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5], Lighting -> "Neutral", PlotRange -> Full, 
  AxesLabel -> {Re[c], Im[c], ""}],
 Graphics3D[{Darker@Green, 
   Sphere[{Re[#], Im[#], Limit[a0 /. {c -> #}, h -> Infinity]}, 0.07] & /@ 
    testvalues}]
 ]
```

[image: Plot of limit vs c]

There are spikes (poles) where the denominator of `a0` is zero:

```
Solve[((4 (h^2 + 1/4 (h^2 + c^2 h^2 + Sqrt[4 h^2 + (h^2 + c^2 h^2)^2])^2)) /. h -> 100) == 0, c] // N
(* -> {{c -> -0.0099995 + 1.00005 I}, {c -> 0.0099995 - 1.00005 I}, {c -> -0.0099995 - 1.00005 I}, {c -> 0.0099995 + 1.00005 I}} *)
```

**How could *Mathematica* get different answers?**

First, it is not a problem with `Simplify` (`a1` above) or `FullSimplify` (`a2` above).  All give the same correct limits with definite values for `c`:

```
Limit[a0 /. {c -> #}, h -> Infinity] & /@ testvalues
Limit[a1 /. {c -> #}, h -> Infinity] & /@ testvalues
Limit[a2 /. {c -> #}, h -> Infinity] & /@ testvalues

(* -> {1, 1, 1/2, 0, 0, 1}
      {1, 1, 1/2, 0, 0, 1}
      {1, 1, 1/2, 0, 0, 1} *)
```

I came up with ways to arrive algebraicallly at the different answers for the limits of `a0` and `a2` for a generic `c`.  I doubt this is how *Mathematica* arrives at its answers, but it shows how the mistake might arise.

To find a limit at infinity, we can replace `h` by `1/k` and let `k` approach 0.  In calculus we learn to simplify the expression until we can plug in `k = 0`.

```
b0 = Simplify[a0 /. h -> 1/k, k > 0]
b2 = Simplify[a2 /. h -> 1/k, k > 0]

(* -> (1 + c^2 + Sqrt[1 + 2 c^2 + c^4 + 4 k^2])^2/(2 (1 + c^4 + 4 k^2 + Sqrt[1 + 2 c^2 + c^4 + 4 k^2] + c^2 (2 + Sqrt[1 + 2 c^2 + c^4 + 4 k^2]))) *)
(* -> (2 k^2)/(1 + c^4 + 4 k^2 - Sqrt[1 + 2 c^2 + c^4 + 4 k^2] - c^2 (-2 + Sqrt[1 + 2 c^2 + c^4 + 4 k^2])) *)

b0 // TeXForm // Print
b2 // TeXForm // Print
```

> $$\frac{\left(c^2+\sqrt{c^4+2 c^2+4 k^2+1}+1\right)^2}{2 \left(c^4+c^2 \left(\sqrt{c^4+2 c^2+4 k^2+1}+2\right)+\sqrt{c^4+2 c^2+4 k^2+1}+4 k^2+1\right)}$$
>
> $$\frac{2 k^2}{c^4-c^2 \left(\sqrt{c^4+2 c^2+4 k^2+1}-2\right)-\sqrt{c^4+2 c^2+4 k^2+1}+4 k^2+1}$$

So far, so good:

```
b0 == b2 // Simplify
(* -> True *)
```

For `b0`, setting `k` to zero yields 1 the same as `Limit[a0, h -> Infinity]`

```
b0 /. k -> 0 // TeXForm
```

> $$\frac{\left(c^2+\sqrt{c^4+2 c^2+1}+1\right)^2}{2
>    \left(c^4+\left(\sqrt{c^4+2 c^2+1}+2\right)
>    c^2+\sqrt{c^4+2 c^2+1}+1\right)}$$

which we can see by multiplying out the numerator and simplifying:

```
b0 /. k -> 0 // Expand // Together
(* -> 1 *)
```

Surprisingly, Simplify does something else and returns

```
b0 /. k -> 0 // Simplify // TeXForm
```

> $$\frac{c^2+\sqrt{\left(c^2+1\right)^2}+1}{2 c^2+2}$$

whose value depends on `c`:

```
% /. {c -> #} & /@ testvalues
(* -> {1, 1, Indeterminate, 0, 0, 1} *)
```

Turning to `b2`, setting `k` to zero yields 0, the same as `Limit[a2, h -> Infinity]`

```
b2 /. k -> 0
(* -> 0 *)
```

As with `a0` and `a2`, the limits of `b0` and `b2` at definite values of `c` are correct:

```
Limit[b0 /. {c -> #}, k -> 0] & /@ testvalues
Limit[b2 /. {c -> #}, k -> 0] & /@ testvalues
(* -> {1, 1, 1/2, 0, 0, 1}
      {1, 1, 1/2, 0, 0, 1} *)
```

### A related example

Change `1+c^2` to `1-c^2`:

```
aIm = a0 /. c -> I c
(* -> (h^2 - c^2 h^2 + Sqrt[4 h^2 + (h^2 - c^2 h^2)^2])^2/(4 (h^2 + 1/4 (h^2 - c^2 h^2 + Sqrt[4 h^2 + (h^2 - c^2 h^2)^2])^2)) *)
```

> $$\frac{\left(-c^2 h^2+\sqrt{\left(h^2-c^2
>    h^2\right)^2+4 h^2}+h^2\right)^2}{4
>    \left(\frac{1}{4} \left(-c^2
>    h^2+\sqrt{\left(h^2-c^2 h^2\right)^2+4
>    h^2}+h^2\right)^2+h^2\right)}$$

Now I'm primarily interest in real `c` and the limit at `h -> Infinity`.
It is similar to previous one above:

$$\begin{cases}
 1        & \left| c\right| <1 \\
 {1}/{2}  & \left| c\right| =1 \\
 0        & \left| c\right| >1
\end{cases}$$

*Mathematica* gives one of the answers by default

```
Limit[aIm, h -> Infinity]
(* -> 1 *)
```

At definite values of `c`, we get the right answers

```
Limit[aIm /. {c -> #}, h -> Infinity] & /@ {0, 1, 2}
(* -> {1, 1/2, 0} *)
```

With various assumptions, one cannot get an answer that depends on `c`.

```
Limit[aIm, h -> Infinity, Assumptions -> c \[Element] Reals]
(* -> 1 *)
```

The correct answer appears in some cases:

```
Limit[aIm, h -> Infinity, Assumptions -> c > 1 || c < -1]
Limit[aIm, h -> Infinity, Assumptions -> c == 1]
Limit[aIm, h -> Infinity, Assumptions -> c == -1]
Limit[aIm, h -> Infinity, Assumptions -> -1 < c < 1]
(* -> 0, 1/2, 1/2, 1 *)
```

These are wrong; the limit is 1/2 in both cases:

```
Limit[aIm, h -> Infinity, Assumptions -> c \[Element] Reals && Abs[c] == 1]
Limit[aIm, h -> Infinity, Assumptions -> c == -1 || c == 1]
(* -> 0, 0 *)
```

### Conclusion

Whatever definite value I set `c` to, I always got the correct limit, but `Limit` does not handle `c` as a symbol correctly.  With some careless algebraic operations, I was able to derive the answers `Limit` gave for original function and the `FullSimplified` version.  Even with `Assumptions` that yield a unique limit, `Limit` does not always give the right answer.  I would be surprised if it were mathematically impossible to develop an algorithm for finding a large class of limits including the OP's, given what can be done for integrals and by standard calculus techniques.  I've never found a lot of use for `Limit`, but perhaps it is because of its limitations.

Comment: I was composing my response and so missed yours until after I posted. What I had to say is pretty much what you said (use assumptions).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I'm not surprised that assumptions affect the limits but I'd call it a bug that we have different values of limits with `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`.

Comment: @Artes No, these discrepancies all follow from the same underlying weaknesses in handling of radicals. The discrepancies themselves are not bugs because the Simplify/FullSimplify rewritings are not incorrect.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Nonetheless I'm not pleased with this issue. I would expect a warning that one should make assumptions on the variables rather than simply different values from limits. Moreover you can see that `Limit[Simplify[...],h->Infinity]` yields different results in `M8` than in `M7` and `M9`.

Comment: WOW! You guys are incredible. So much great information. I have one question regarding syntax though: is your `Block[{$Assumptions = c \[Element] Reals}, Limit[a0, h -> Infinity]]` equivalent to `Limit[a0, h -> Infinity , Assumptions->c \[Element] Reals]` ? And if not, how so?

Comment: @Kagaratsch They're pretty much equivalent.  With `Block` you can temporarily reset global variables.  `$Assumptions` is used by many functions, including `Limit`.  All or most such functions provide an `Assumptions` option to do the same thing.  Using the option seems easier here, but I've got used to using `$Assumptions` inside a `Block` when testing things.  You can cut and paste things into it, and my assumptions are up front and not buried in the options.  You can use `Block` to wrap several commands that all have the same assumptions, for instance.

Comment: One thing Limit, with assumptions, is quite good for is Integrate. regarding incorrect results when using assumptions involving equalities, not much surprise there (at least to me). An assumption such as c==1||c==-1 places c in a measure zero family that is in general quite difficult to handle algorithmically. I state this as one who has worked on the innards of such things; others who have done likewise may have different experiences.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I was thinking that with current algorithms, limits must be difficult, because I assume Mathematica uses the best available, but I was speculating better ways might yet be developed.  Integration has seemed a more important problem than limits (in my parochial view).  Perhaps that is why integration algorithms seem more developed.  With regard to zero-measure subsets, that's where the interesting limits tend to occur.  I was surprised that `c==1` is ok but not `c==1||c==-1`, but I can imagine they invoke different procedures

Comment: My guess is the simplification procedures, when given an assumption like c==1, pretty much do a substitution. With the disjunction they do not do that, and probably don't derive much other benefit. I guess what I'm trying to say is simplification has its weak spots, and integrality assumptions in general do not fare well in my experience.

Answer (score 12):

It is a bug in Series. Note that

```
a := (h^2 + c^2 h^2 + Sqrt[4 h^2 + (h^2 + c^2 h^2)^2])^2/( 4 (h^2 + 1/4 (h^2 + c^2 h^2 + Sqrt[4 h^2 + (h^2 + c^2 h^2)^2])^2))
b = FullSimplify[a]
Series[a,{h,Infinity,0}]
(* Out: 1 + O[1/h]^2 *)
Series[b,{h,Infinity,0}]
(* Out: O[1/h]^2 *)
```

The fact is that for $h\to\infty$ there are two terms cancelling each other in the denominator of $b$, one of which is a square root.

In fact further assumptions make it work

```
Assuming[c >= 0, Simplify@Series[b, {h, Infinity, 0}]]
(* Out: 1 + O[1/h]^2 *)
Assuming[c <= 0, Simplify@Series[b, {h, Infinity, 0}]]
(* Out: 1 + O[1/h]^2 *)
```

Answer (score 12):

This is a known limitation in `Series` and `Limit`. `Series` does not handle roots in a flawless manner. For example, here is an expansion at the branch point (zero) that is only "half" correct.

```
In[4]:= Series[Sqrt[x^2], {x,0,2}]                                              

                3
Out[4]= x + O[x]
```

This is fine for re(x)>0, but not so good for re(x)<0 in a neighborhood of the origin.

`Limit` has the ability to handle this situation if provided sufficiently strong assumptions. For this example one could do as follows.

```
a = (h^2 + c^2 h^2 + 
      Sqrt[4 h^2 + (h^2 + c^2 h^2)^2])^2/(4 *(h^2 + 
       1/4 (h^2 + c^2 h^2 + Sqrt[4 h^2 + (h^2 + c^2 h^2)^2])^2));

a2 = FullSimplify[a];

Limit[a2, h -> Infinity, Assumptions -> Element[c, Reals]]

(* Out[80]= 1 *)
```

This next one is actually not so good.

```
Limit[a, h -> Infinity]

(* Out[63]= 1 *)
```

That is to say, while the original result was what the poster wanted, it is only by accident of haw some symbolic radicals were handled. Here is why it is not fully correct: for "many" values of `c` the limit is not 1.

```
Limit[{a, a2} /. c -> 2 I, h -> Infinity]

(* Out[81]= {0, 0} *)
```

Indeed, there is an interplay between real and imaginary parts that determines the limiting behavior.

```
Limit[{a, a2} /. c -> 1 - 2 I, h -> Infinity]

(* Out[85]= {0, 0} *)

Limit[{a, a2} /. c -> 3 - 2 I, h -> Infinity]

(* Out[86]= {1, 1} *)
```

As for bug reports, this one is in the data base and has been for quite some time. It is unlikely to change unless and until there is some redesign both of `Series` and `Limit`.

Comment: Yes, I figured we must have been writing simultaneously.  As you said, our solution is basically the same: use assumptions.

Answer (score 10):

Let's define :

```
a1 = (h^2 + c^2 h^2 + 
  Sqrt[4 h^2 + (h^2 + c^2 h^2)^2])^2/(4 (h^2 + 
   1/4 (h^2 + c^2 h^2 + Sqrt[4 h^2 + (h^2 + c^2 h^2)^2])^2));

a2 = a1 // Simplify

a3 = a1 // FullSimplify
```

[image]

**Mathematica 7 and 9**

```
Limit[ #, h -> Infinity]& /@ {a1, a2, a3}
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 0}
> ```

while assuming that `c` is a real number :

```
Limit[#, h -> Infinity, Assumptions -> c ∈  Reals] & /@ {a1, a2, a3}
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1}
> ```

**Mathematica 8**

```
Limit[#, h -> Infinity]& /@ {a1, a2, a3}
```

[image]

assuming that `c` is a real number :

```
Limit[#, h -> Infinity, Assumptions -> c ∈  Reals] & /@ {a1, a2, a3}
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1}
> ```

**Conclusions**

All versions (`7, 8, 9`) return the same expressions respectively for `a1`, `a2` and  `a3`.

There is a serious problem in `Limit` at least since the version `7` ( seems like `WRI` emploees are aware of it). The way we simplify the expressions shouldn't affect its limits. So there should be a warning on possible inconsistencies.

Comment: Thank you, I will report it. I accepted the answer of Fabian since he has fewer points than you and therefore would benifit more from it. Hope that is alright.

Comment: @Kagaratsch it is recommended that you select the answer that actually helps you the most, or when you cannot decide the oldest answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: In this case both answers correctly identified the problem as bug, so I was undecided. However, the answer of Fabian came 3 minutes earlier, so I am glad to know that apparently I did the right thing.